# Unable to find xml tag using Beautiful Soup in a loop

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have a block of xml content that varies depending on a code I submit through an API. The fetching process works fine. The xml tags I want to extract vary depending on the code. The function that determines the list of tags also works correctly.

I have been successful in extracting information from a block of content in xml, however in a certain report that I fetch there are multiple items in the content block with the same tags I wish to extract. I have split the content into several items by the tag `<item>` and removed the first index as it is not useful to me.

Now I want to search each item by my list of tags (which previously worked fine until I introduced multiple items and looped over them).

I have checked that each item `i` can be 'seen' in the `for n in list` loop by printing `i` and it appears correctly. But when it comes to searching the string it doesn't seem to be recognised since printing each var just shows as 'None' (on the note I have confirmed that each `i` is a string). The terms I am searching are 100% in the content, this process works until I introduce the `for i in items` loop.

```
def parser(content, report_code ):
    list = list_type(report_code)
    items = content.split('<item>')
    items.pop(0)
    for i in items:
        arr = []
        for n in list:
            print i
            var = BeautifulSoup(i, "xml").find(n)
            var = str(var).split('>')[1].split('<')[0].strip()
            print var
            arr.append(var)
    return arr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this I have found some solution to my problem.

The above code worked for me when I wasn't splitting `'content'` by `<item>`. It turned out content had type `'bytes'` and the BeautifulSoup parser worked with this. However when I split content by `<item>` and looped over each i as above, the input to BeautifulSoup `(i in items)` was now of type `'str'`. I was surprised that this didn't work in BeautifulSoup to be honest.

After further research I came across `bytes()` and `bytearray()`, 2 built-in functions that convert strings to bytes amongst other things. But I was also having trouble with this. Maybe someone with more knowledge can explain how to properly use these functions.

In the end I figured out another structure of going about the above code. I instead looped over each `var` in the output of `findAll` in BeautifulSoup. I also included an exception for cases where nothing was found, which was also throwing an error.

```
def parser(content, report_code ):
  list = list_type(report_code)
  data = []
  for n in list:
    arr = []
    try:
       for var in BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml-xml").findAll(n):
          var = str(var).split('>')[1].split('<')[0].strip()
          arr.append(var)
    except IndexError:
       pass
    data.append(arr)
```